# Intercepting drag and drop events in a compound component?

Tags: java, swing, events, drag-and-drop

Say I have a JPanel containing some JTextFields. I would like to perform the same drop action for this JPanel and its children. In other words, I would like the drop action onto the children to be treated the same way as a drop action onto the JPanel.

Is there any other way other than setting the same DropTargetListener for the JPanel and its children?

---

1. I know that if I set the TransferHandler of those JTextFields to null, the JPanel will receive the drag and drop event. However, this will destroy the copy and paste functionality of the textfield.
2. I know that I can intercept mouse events with JLayer. Is there something like this for drag events?

---

In the end, I added listeners separately to the child components. Because I needed the drop location relative to the parent as well, I used SwingUtilities.convertToPoint() separately on the child components. Which means a lot of different listeners used -- more memory usage. But seems to be the best way for now.

Comment: Have you tried registering the same `DropTargetListener` when you create a new instance of `DropTarget`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes. I was wondering if there was any alternative way? Because I have a lot of these type of components (which are nested too). And don't really want to use a recursive loop to add the listeners.

Comment: Drag'n'Drop works this way, it will only provide notifications to components that it can "see" per say...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to drop items on a panel but you want any components on the panel to be ignored for dropping purposes you can deactivate the drop target on each of the components added to the panel. You will still be able to cut and paste within them, and there is even a way to initiate a drag from them, but you won't be able to drop anything on them - the drop event goes straight through them to the drop target associated with the panel.

To do this, simply call

```
component.getDropTarget().setActive(false);
```

for each component on the panel.

I found this useful when building a calendar panel where I wanted to be able to drag appointments around but drop them on the panel even if it was (partially or completely) covered in other appointments.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you had in mind, but, I basically added the same `DropTargetListener` to all of my components, which meant that it didn't matter where I dragged/dropped the incoming request, all the components triggered the same events...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.dnd.DnDConstants;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTarget;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDragEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDropEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestDragNDrop100 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new TestDragNDrop100();

    }

    public TestDragNDrop100() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel implements DropTargetListener {

        public TestPane() {

            DropTarget dt = new DropTarget(this, DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE, this, true);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
                gbc.gridy = y;
                for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
                    gbc.gridx = x;
                    JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
                    DropTarget child = new DropTarget(field, DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE, this, true);
                    add(field, gbc);
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
            System.out.println("DragEnter - " + dtde.getDropTargetContext().getComponent());
        }

        @Override
        public void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
            System.out.println("DragOver - " + dtde.getDropTargetContext().getComponent());
        }

        @Override
        public void dropActionChanged(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
            System.out.println("dropActionChanged" + dtde.getDropTargetContext().getComponent());
        }

        @Override
        public void dragExit(DropTargetEvent dte) {
            System.out.println("dragExit" + dte.getDropTargetContext().getComponent());
        }

        @Override
        public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
            System.out.println("drop" + dtde.getDropTargetContext().getComponent());
        }

    }

}
```

I should also note.  I tested the fields cut/copy/paste functionality and had no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a custom TransferHandler on the container which delegates to its children as appropriate, something along the lines of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    parent.add(new JTextField("item" + i, 20));
};
TransferHandler handler = new TransferHandler() {

    @Override
    public boolean canImport(TransferSupport support) {
        TransferHandler childHandler = getTargetHandler();
        return childHandler.canImport(
                getTargetSupport(support));
    }

    protected TransferSupport getTargetSupport(TransferSupport support) {
        return new TransferSupport(getTarget(), support.getTransferable());
    }

    protected TransferHandler getTargetHandler() {
        return getTarget().getTransferHandler();
    }

    protected JComponent getTarget() {
        return (JComponent) parent.getComponent(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean importData(TransferSupport support) {
        return getTargetHandler().importData(getTargetSupport(support));
    }

};
parent.setTransferHandler(handler);
```